# Setting up multiple small sites

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7

I have no experience with Drupal.

I'm looking to use a cms but I have a requirement that, while it sounds simple, I'm not sure how easy, or possible, the implementation will be.

I have many small sites (let's say 100). Each site is basically setup the same way except the content and images are different.  Each site would need an admin(s) that would manage content and have the ability to add new pages where needed.

Is Drupal the kind of cms that could handle requirements like this or is there another cms that is more suited for this kind of implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is definitely suited to this, you should use the latest version (Drupal 7) and perform a multisite installation. That way you can keep the same core code base (which will make updating Drupal a cinch across 100 or so sites).

Have a look in the `/sites/default/example.sites.php` file for instructions on how to set it up, and if you get stuck post another question on here and I'm sure someone will be able to help.

**EDIT**

In fact there's a guide to the installation [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/121989).